# Aosp 14 build error [100% 1/1] analyzing Android.bp files and generating ninja file at out/soong/build.ninja FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja

Tags: android, android-source

cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_out "out/soong"     --out
"out"     -o out/soong/build.ninja --bazel-mode --globListDir build --globFile out/soong/globs-build.ninja -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --
used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.build Android.bp
Killed
11:34:29 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
This is the error im facing can someone help me out...

Cant understand the error to try anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. After increasing the swap file size to 32gb, it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling to build with less than recommended RAM, a couple of things I noticed while fixing the build in my hexacore CPU with 16Gb RAM,

1. Make sure the RAM + SWAP is greater than 32GB, I recommend ~34GB. Based on other processes running in the Machine, increase it.
2. Increase the swappiness to closer to 100. I recommend ~80. This will more frequently empty RAM for processing.
3. Run the build with half
   of the capability of your machine. If you have a machine capable of 12 threads, try to reduce the threads for build to 6. This will
   provide room for any additional running processes including the swap process. If it works, try increasing the threads to reduce build time, or else try reducing threads.

   make -j6

Answer (score -1):

Refer below blog to increase swap memory

[https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-increase-swap-space-in-ubuntu/][1]

```
grep Swap /proc/meminfo
```

Resize Swap to 8GB

```
# Turn swap off
# This moves stuff in swap to the main memory and might take several minutes
sudo swapoff -a
# Create an empty swapfile
# Note that "1G" is basically just the unit and count is an integer.
# Together, they define the size. In this case 8GB.
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
# Set the correct permissions
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile  # Set up a Linux swap area
sudo swapon /swapfile  # Turn the swap on
 
 
Check if it worked
 
grep Swap /proc/meminfo
 
 
Make it permanent (persist on restarts)
Add this line to the end of your /etc/fstab:
 
/swapfile swap swap sw 0 0
```